# How to Automate e-signature input using Selenium?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, canvas

Can anybody suggest what is the method to automate e-signature input in selenium ?

I have tried using the action class to draw a line on the canvas object . Below is the code :

```
    Actions actionBuilder=new Actions(driver);          
Action drawOnCanvas=actionBuilder
            .contextClick(canvas_div)
            .moveToElement(wbCanvas,8,8)
            .clickAndHold(wbCanvas)
            .moveByOffset(120, 120)
            .moveByOffset(60,70)
            .moveByOffset(-140,-140)
            .release(canvas_div)
            .build();
    drawOnCanvas.perform();
```

Selenium is able to identify the canvas element. I can see the mouse movement but nothing is drawn on the canvas element.

Manually it is taking input from a e-signature device. 
Below is the HTML code for the element

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" id="canvas_div">
                            <canvas height="75" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" id="eSignatureDialog_canvas" style="border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); border-image: none;" name="eSignatureDialog_canvas">
                            </canvas>
                        </div>
```

Comment: What kind of "e-signature device" is this? Is it in hardware, is it a library etc? This will probably depend on how the device / library works, so it would be good to know which one it is.

Comment: it is a hardware device . I have checked the HTML before and after the signature is captured but there is no change . It is handled using Javascript

Comment: Well, what about telling us _which_ device it is? We cannot read your mind...

Comment: Topaz System Inc

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine, maybe except for this:

```
.contextClick(canvas_div)
```

... which could be:

```
.click(wbCanvas)
```

[Here](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager-examples/blob/master/src/test/java/io/github/bonigarcia/wdm/test/CanvasTest.java) you have a similar working example.